# How to point RemoteWebDriver to one of the multiple standalone docker selenium standalone chrome browsers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've requirement to run test cases on separate chrome browsers running inside docker container.

I've install chrome docker containers as below

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1-francium

docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5901:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1-francium
```

- I have scripts which does unique tasks like analytics testing, performance testing etc so I can't use Grid approach here.
- This is what I do in case of single chrome browser but I need to point to a particular docker container image

  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                                  new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), 
                                  DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

Comment: bind the port to the standalone server with a different port nulber: `docker run -d -p 5900:4444 -v ...` and `docker run -d -p 5901:4444 -v ...` . Then connect to standalone server with `new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("http://localhost:5900/wd/hub")` or `new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5901/wd/hub")` for the second instance.

Comment: Thanks let me try it & update back.  Can you please explain in details "...-d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900..".  I couldn't find any good documentation for this @FlorentB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with help of comment from @Flore B.

```
docker run -d -p 5902:4444 -p 5903:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1-francium
```

RemoteWebDriver url

```
http://0.0.0.0:5902/wd/hub
```